# Laravel Auth attempt() not working despite correct credentials

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, jwt

I am currently writing an Authentication controller for my Laravel API application, and I have decided to authenticate my system with [JWT-Auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth).

I am attempting to login using valid credentials, yet the `JWTAuth::attempt()` method returns false.

Here's my controller

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    $user = User::where('email', $credentials['email'])->where('active', 1)->first();
    if ($user && $token = $this->auth->attempt($credentials)) {
        $remember = true;
        event(new Login($this->auth->user(), $remember));
        return $token;
    }
}
```

I feel like the error lies somewhere in my configuration.

Any ideas what might be triggering this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to discover the issue.

I had to hash the password using [Illuminate Hash](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/hashing) for the `attempt()` method to work correctly.